# paste a grep string in R

Tags: r, string, awk

need to write a file with a varierty of paramters. The command looks like

```
awk 'match($0, /^\[[0-9]*\]/) {print substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)}' testdata > out
```

when I then try to paste it in R

```
 paste("awk 'match($0, /^\[[0-9]*\]/) {print substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)}'")
    Error: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""awk 'match($0, /^\[
```

can somebody tell me how I get around that error and paste that string correctly in R?

Comment: `paste("awk 'match($0, /^\\[[0-9]*\\]/) {print substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)}'")`

Comment: please provide an example string and the expected response

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` character, as `\[`is not a valid escape sequence to `\\[`. A similar argument holds for `\]`.

The correct call is thus

```
paste("awk 'match($0, /^\\[[0-9]*\\]/) {print substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)}'")
```